# install protobuf php on wamp php 7.4

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, wamp

I need to use a protobuff on windows 10 with php 7.4 x64 installed. How can I get a dll for this extension? I did search on the internet and found only for 5.6 version. How to build or find this extension for 7.4?

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild#building_pecl_extensions